# Check for certain statements in Swift closure

Tags: swift, closures

I wrote a function which takes a closure as an argument like this:

```
func doSome(work: () -> Void = { print("sleeping...") } ) {
    work()
}
```

Now I would like to investigate the `work` done.
Therefore I want to check if the given closure contains any print statements.

Somehow like this:

```
func doSome(work: () -> Void = { print("doing hard work...") } ) {
    work()

    if work.contains(print) {
        print("we did some hard work there and printed something!")
    }
}
```

How can I achieve that?

---

**EDIT: What I am trying to achieve**

An async function tries to connect to an http server - let's call it `connect`. It takes a closure as its parameter - called `finally`. As its name already indicates: the closure gets executed after the connecting attempt.

If the connecting attempt succeeds (http response code == 200), I need to call another function ONCE - let's call it so: `once`.

The `connect` function therefore looks like this:

```
func connect(finally: () -> Void = {}) {
    httpRepsonse = asyncRequestToServer()

    if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
        once()
    }

    // and finally:
    finally()
}
```

Other functions call `connect` and pass over their statements that they need for the connect function to execute `finally`.

And here comes the problem: there is one function that needs `once` executed every time, therefore it passes it over in the `finally` closure. If the connecting now succeeds, `once` gets called twice.

That's why I wanted to check the given closure already contains the `once` call, so I could avoid calling it twice.

Comment: Swift doesn't have this kind of retrospective capability. For one, code is optimized, lots of functions are in-lined, etc, which makes it quite hard to tell what the original function calls looked like

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this? Maybe we can suggest a more feasible apporach

Comment: so if I understand it, there is an instance in which the `finally` block contains a call to `once()` that should happen even in the case of the status code being non 200, but if the status code happens to be 200, you don't want 2 `once` calls to occur?

Comment: @Alexander yes, you understood it correctly. I thought I could just easily "have a look inside" the given closure. But another Boolean parameter (or expecting a closure resulting in a Boolean value) would be the easiest solution

Comment: Rather than having this scaffolding you put in, which is essentially "do this to suite most cases, then figure out how to treat the special case differently", I would just the HTTP response into the closure, so that each closure can define exactly how it responds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interrogating a closure for its contents is not easily done as far as I know.

You could do a workaround (depending on your needs and implementation of course) using one or more Boolean arguments which you would assign when calling the function, if relevant.

For example:

```
func doSome(work: () -> Void = { print("doing hard work...")}, containsPrint: Bool = false) {

    // Call your work closure
    work()

    // Check conditions
    if containsPrint {
        print("We printed some stuff")
    }
}
```

I am aware that this is a rather simple *solution* but it might provide the required functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use a global variable that you change whenever you print to the console, and check it inside you `doSome(work:)`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: You can't. As Alexander says, Swift does not support this. You would have to add some sort of housekeeping, as suggested in Carpsen90's answer.

Comment: Do you have an idea for my situation? (I updated my post)